# Change Python Interpreter

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, jython, raspberry-pi2

I am having troubles with figuring out how to temporarily change my Raspberry Pi 2's Python interpreter to the Jython interpreter.

There is one thing that confuses with adding the Jython interpreter, and that is when you add the Jython interpreter, it is a 'jar' file that I must put as the interpreter, I am just curious if that will change anything.

*(Note: I already have Jython installed and ready on my Pi)*

*(Note: I am a newcomer to Linux and the Pi)*

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: if you are using debian/ubuntu, simply install jython: apt-get install jython
.    then you can enter interpreter by using jython command. why are you trying to change interpreter? I think it will break some of your apps.

Comment: @Veedrac I have made some Jython code for my Raspberry Pi, and I want to run it on there.

Comment: @AmirH I already have it installed. And I want to at least add a new interpreter so I can run Jython on my Pi.

Comment: Open a command prompt and write `jython`. What happens? If that worked, write `jython your_python_file.py` to run the code.

Comment: add "#!/usr/bin/jython'' as first line of your script? (why do you want to use jython? python can do almost anything you want...)